# Deluge loses track of .torrent after reboot

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

I have a problem with Deluge which I don't understand why it's happening.
So I download a torrent, all works fine untill the next boot when Deluge practically "forget" that I already downloaded those torrents and it starts downloading them again or just gives "Error" like you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

I have to mention that I download the files on a NTFS partition, if that helps in any way.Why is this happening and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mount the partition where you saved files and then check the data. problem is the partition where you saved files was not mounted.

so mount it & select choose check data option.

hope that helps.

Comment: It's mounted...


I tried to set location and then force re-check but after re-checking it just starts to download the torrent again...

Comment: Seems like you were right mate. I didn't know that I have to access the partition to mount it, and when I checked if it's mounted or not ? Guess what, it was mounted, because I accessed it before to check if it's mounted.