# Fixing Deluge Torrent Error After Reboot

Tags: deluge

I'm having troubles with Deluge torrent client.

1. After rebooting my computer, I will have to open / quit few times before I could force re-check and start seeding again.
2. Tried to download some files and they give me Input / Output error and Deluge doesn't download the files.

I really would like to use Deluge. However these two problems makes it impossible to use it.

I checked the question here; [Deluge loses track of .torrent after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393077/deluge-loses-track-of-torrent-after-reboot)

Unfortunately I'm not using external drive. I'm keeping the files on my secondary drive (internal).

Is there any work around these troubles?

P.S. I'm a Linux newbie.

Comment: Is your secondary drive mounted before you start Deluge?

Comment: @Cas Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, do a `killall deluged` in terminal before rebooting.